Filter multiple option in Tanstack table in Reactjs
I want to ask about implementing a filter function with multiple options like in the picture. I am using Tanstack table. I have researched and found only instructions for using the default filter. I can't find specific instructions for handling the filter below. Thank you.
I have tried to research in the documentation of Tanstack table, but I don't see how to change the search options
This is example:
